# TypeScript: Have return type depend on parameter

Tags: typescript, types, overloading, conditional-types

I have the following TypeScript function:

```
declare function getUserContext(
  options: UserContextOptions
): Promise<UserContext>;

declare function getTeamContext(
  options: TeamContextOptions
): Promise<TeamContext>;

type UserContextWithoutSlackTeamOptions = Omit<
  UserContextOptions,
  'slackTeamRef'
>;

async function getContext<
  T extends
    | TeamContextOptions
    | (TeamContextOptions & UserContextWithoutSlackTeamOptions)
>(
  options: Partial<UserContextWithoutSlackTeamOptions> & T
): Promise<
  T extends UserContextWithoutSlackTeamOptions
    ? TeamContext & UserContext
    : TeamContext
> {
  const teamContext = await getTeamContext(options);
  const userContext = options.user
    ? await getUserContext({
        user: options.user,
        slackTeamRef: teamContext.slackTeam,
      })
    : undefined;

  return {
    ...teamContext,
    ...userContext,
    octokit: userContext.octokit ?? teamContext.octokit,
  };
}
```

and here are the interfaces:

```
interface UserContextOptions {
  user: {
    id: string;
    name?: string;
  };
  slackTeamRef: string;
}

interface TeamContextOptions {
  teamId: string;
}

interface TeamContext {
  slackTeam: string;
  octokit: string;
}

interface UserContext {
  user: string | null | undefined;
  slackUser: string;
  octokit: string | undefined;
}
```

Logically, I would think this would work, however TypeScript complains in several places:

In the `return` statement, it says

```
TS2322: Type '{ octokit: string; user?: string | null | undefined; slackUser?: string | undefined; slackTeam: string; }' is not assignable to type 'TeamContext & UserContext'.  
 Type '{ octokit: string; user?: string | null | undefined; slackUser?: string | undefined; slackTeam: string; }' is not assignable to type 'UserContext'.    
 Property 'user' is optional in type '{ octokit: string; user?: string | null | undefined; slackUser?: string | undefined; slackTeam: string; }' but required in type 'UserContext'.

TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

I have looked at numerous other SO posts, but none of the solutions I have come across have been applicable to this specific scenario.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdoGED24IAeYA8gA5jB7rIDeAsAFDLICumUAXLY888ACZd0YKKADmAbh68QcALYQA-EJHipTZAF91zdABtEAawAqEeQCUIMFaJCTGmxo1CRYiFKfm58RMhSrcGpDyAJKCyMK29gyODM74bkjInnLekESBugYIJmZyNmrSOAhgOIbAYAV26rHxrvBJGNh46WCZrOxVYsgAPsggLHp6vawg-FagEPw6EdmGTZwRqtVFJWUVXSMsYxMgUzVODOMIBlAoMNsllCDIYhBgC2mEYAAUReTX6FyPLc9+n4wAJRcAAKUBwcmAmAAPD8fGAAHzqRjHU7nS7+G53MApJ5EN4aHAfKhcXG-XzEkDoIGg8GQmFk+FIw6ouBnZAXEBXPC3e5w1oE5hEzFfNDsPEkSnUhjA5BgiFQiCw8XkxHIo4QE5s9FczG8nF5CWC5DCz6kw2q-5UGlyumK6GM1rMuIMMAAT1IKH5zwA6hUABY4FhgADKcxSVqpyAAvMhiJCwNDpN6KSKADTSADk+iMKUsMEzjGdjDg6DdXI5GOu+olSY0xmQzwgY2lvBGjr+UukzD6Lw7qc+yAAZGLmvC-WBA8Gw7m8pH0ICi8bTSS5WyKHA9Mqx60J1PQ+G51KEcPkjb5fSldIG02W6OoBK90GD7P5PPu8hFMkLfDTymwB+5peKqRbtAgVBtMEqSqjGyBwAA7nAFT6v2rwrlSgIzOBVJtGwO7PLB6HoAAdHhUAfl+CFIW02L-i89AaG2zBkVwRGkewGaMUxOY5HmVhcFBErETxuTyJxTFaIuXFcNs4wwJM0yHMwZxgCwUA3AxbbEdpgmquJvDaex+FEPpQprOUlQdMZYDEcUpQWZ+X66fCtnmRU+naA4hxAA)

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link to code)](https://tsplay.dev/w8vd4m), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: @jcalz apologies, just edited it

Comment: Hmm, you seem to be modifying your code quite a bit here now, to the point where you're not even using overloads at all, and you've stopped talking about the call site problem.  Maybe I'll come back tomorrow to see if this question has stabilized enough to be worth working on.

Comment: @jcalz sorry for all the changes, I've been making improvements and realizing that I had a logic error. I promise its all good now and stable :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Function Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) is designed for this

```js
async function getContext(options: TeamContextOptions & UserContextWithoutSlackTeamOptions): Promise<TeamContext & UserContext>;
async function getContext(options: TeamContextOptions): Promise<TeamContext>;
async function getContext(
  options: TeamContextOptions & UserContextWithoutSlackTeamOptions | TeamContextOptions & Partial<UserContextWithoutSlackTeamOptions>
) {
  // impl...
}

declare const teamOption: TeamContextOptions
declare const mixOption: TeamContextOptions & UserContextWithoutSlackTeamOptions

async () => {
  const v1 = await getContext(teamOption) // TeamContext
  const v2 = await getContext(mixOption) // TeamContext & UserContext
}
```